# why does findFragmentById always returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I am attempting get my fragment using findFragmentById but every time I get null in its place, I have also tried using findFragmentByTag and adding a tag to my add transaction, but that also does the same.

The following code is a modified blank starting template (for simplicity's sake)

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.container);

    if (placeholderFragment == null) {
        Log.i("TAG", "placeholderFragment is null");
    } else {
        Log.i("TAG", "placeholderFragment is not null");
    }
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

I have tried replacing the add with `add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment(), "TAG")` then attempt to access it with `findFragmentByTag("TAG")` also to no success.

how can I get my code to work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to find it immediately after you add the `Fragment`. In that little time the `Fragment` is probably not added yet.

What you can you is that you already have the fragment while you are adding it.

`findFragmentById()` function is generally for accessing `Fragments` in other functions after you already added them for a while.

Here is an example

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, placeholderFragment).commit();
    }
}

public void anotherFunc() {

    PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
}
```